# plot scatter dots with normalised dot sizes?

Tags: python, r, ggplot2, plot

Can I ask how to plot the figure? The size of each dot should correspond to its proportion at a particular time.

Can arrows or continues lines also be used to show the trend instead of discrete dots? The width of the arrow/line will correspond to its proportion at a particular time. Also, it can handle missing data, e.g. set the position of missing data as blank or use a very thin arrow/line for missing data.

Both `python` and `R` are good for me.

Raw data:

```
Time;Value A;Value A proportion;Value B;Value B proportion
1;5;90%;12;10%
2;7;80%;43;20%
3;7;80%;83;20%
4;8;70%;44;30%
5;10;80%;65;20%
```

An example of the plot is like this, but I am happy for other dot patterns.

[image: p]

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. Is the plot showing your desired output?

Comment: Use matplotlib scatter and scale the size keyword based on your proportion

Comment: @yifyan I modified my question. They are just an example based on the raw data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

myDF <- read.table("~/Desktop/test.txt",header=TRUE,sep=";")
# remove "%"
myDF <- data.frame(lapply(myDF, function(x) as.numeric(sub("%", "", x))) )

meltVar <- melt(myDF,id.vars = c("Time"),measure.vars = c("Value.A","Value.B"))
meltpropr <- melt(myDF,id.vars = c("Time"),measure.vars = c("Value.A.proportion","Value.B.proportion"))
newDF <- as.data.frame(cbind(meltVar,meltpropr[,"value"]))
names(newDF) <- c("Time","variable","value","prop")

ggplot(newDF,aes(x=Time, y=value)) + geom_point(aes(colour=variable , shape=variable, size = prop))
```

[image]

You can play with `aes` and `theme` to get the figure as you like.